# php json_decode is not working Properly

Tags: php, json

When i am Decoding using commented "$jsonString" String it is working very well.
But after using curl it is not working, showing Null.

Please Help Me in this.

```
if (isset($_POST['dkno'])) {
  $dcktNo = $_POST['dkno'];
  $url = 'http://ExampleStatus.php?dkno=' . $dcktNo;
  $myvars = '';

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $jsonString = curl_exec($ch);
  // $jsonString = '[{"branchname":"BHUBNESHWAR","consignee":"ICICI BANK LTD","currentstatus":"Delivered by : BHUBNESHWAR On - 25/07/2015 01:00","dlyflag":"Y","PODuploaded":"Not Uploaded"}]';

  if ($jsonString != '') {
    $json = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $jsonString);
    echo $json;

    $obj = json_decode($json);
        if (is_null($obj)) {
          die("<br/>Invalid JSON, don't need to keep on working on it");
        } else {
          $podStatus = $obj->PODuploaded;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it shows null. What shows null?

Comment: Call json_last_error() and json_last_error_msg() after your json_decode call so you can debug it properly.

Comment: So it seems like the problem is the curl, not json_decode. But you havenn't provided enough information for anyone to really help. Good luck

Comment: If you do `echo curl_exec($ch);`, what does it say? And your URL looks weird - maybe this is not the JSON that your are looking for? ;) And if your JSON /looks/ right: Is it UTF-8?

Comment: what does echo $json; show?

Comment: echo $json; shows following line

`{"branchname":"BHUBNESHWAR","consignee":"ICICI BANK LTD","currentstatus":"Delivered by : BHUBNESHWAR On - 25/07/2015 01:00","dlyflag":"Y","PODuploaded":"1261447.jpg"}`

and echo curl_exec($ch); shows following line with square Bracket

`[{"branchname":"BHUBNESHWAR","consignee":"ICICI BANK LTD","currentstatus":"Delivered by : BHUBNESHWAR On - 25/07/2015 01:00","dlyflag":"Y","PODuploaded":"1261447.jpg"}]`

if i am running $obj = json_decode($json); without if block it shows following Error Message

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

After curl I used following concept to get only JSON data from HTML Page.

1) fetchData.php

```
$url = 'http://DocketStatusApp.aspx?dkno=' . $dcktNo;
$myvars = '';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$jsonString = curl_exec($ch);

// now get only value
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($jsonString);
$thediv = $dom->getElementById('Label1');
echo $thediv->textContent;
```

2) JSONprocess.php

```
 if (isset($_POST['dkno'])) {
    $dcktNo = $_POST['dkno'];

    ob_start(); // begin collecting output
    include_once 'fetchData.php';
    $result = ob_get_clean(); // Completed collecting output

  // Now it will show & take only JSON Data from Div Tag
  $json = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $result);

  $obj = json_decode($json);
  if (is_null($obj)) {
     die("<br/>Invalid JSON, don't need to keep on working on it");
   } else {
    $podStatus = $obj->PODuploaded;
   }
}
```